# copy columns and rows based on two criteria in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

Here's a tough one got this code and I can search two criteria but I can't for the life of me alter this to allow me to search two criteria in two different columns. i.e H and AC.

then of both met copy those rows into a new sheet

```
Dim a As String, b As String
a = InputBox("Enter first criteria")
b = InputBox("enter second criteria")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=a
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=b
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks.Add
Range("A2").PasteSpecial
x = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
Range("H" & x + 1).Formula = "=sum(H2:H" & x & ")"
Range("H" & x + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("H" & x + 1 & ":BC" & x + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Data for " & a & " and " & b & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter
MsgBox "Complete" & Chr(10) & " check the file Data for " & a & " and " & b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure I understand your question, you can filter on columns H and AC by changing the field references in the two Autofilter statements to `Field:=8` and `Field:=29`, respectively.